# MapServer with Oracle-Spatial on Linux

Tags: mapserver, oracle-spatial

On a SUSE System (SLES 15) I try to configure MapServer 7.4. with Oracle-Spatial support.
Important: The Oracle Database is installed on another server.

I wonder if I need also the Oracle installation on the SLES 15-server or if the Oracle client is enough?
So far I installed the client at /usr/lib64/oracle/11.2.0.4.0/client/lib/

I try to configure with:

cmake ..   -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/lib64:/usr/share/gdal:/usr/lib64/oracle/11.2.0.4.0/client/lib 
-DWITH_ORACLESPATIAL=1 -DWITH_HARFBUZZ=0 -DWITH_GIF=0 -DWITH_FCGI=0 -DWITH_PROTOBUFC=0 -DWITH_FRIBIDI=0

but in the output I always get:
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:73 (message):
  ORACLESPATIAL library/component/dependency could not be found.

Does that mean I definitely need an Oracle installation?

Comment: No you shouldn't.  Try setting `ORACLE_HOME` env var to `/usr/share/gdal:/usr/lib64/oracle/11.2.0.4.0/client` as per https://mapserver.org/el/installation/unix.html

Answer (score 2):

Alright, finally I got it.

I declared:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${ORACLE_HOME}:/usr/lib
```

and in my case I got a problem with the ORACLE_INCLUDE_DIR.

I changed in the cmake-directory cmake/FindOracle.cmake:

```
 if(DEFINED ENV{ORACLE_HOME})    
 27   
 28   set(ORACLE_HOME $ENV{ORACLE_HOME})    
 29   message("ORACLE_HOME=${ORACLE_HOME}")   
 30   
 31   find_path(ORACLE_INCLUDE_DIR
 32     NAMES oci.h
 33     PATHS
 34
 35     /usr/include/oracle/12.2/client64)
```

And I configured mapserver by:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE='debug' -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/mapserver -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64:/usr/include/oracle/12.2/client64:
/usr/lib:/usr/lib64:/usr/share/gdal -DWITH_ORACLESPATIAL=1 -DWITH_PROTOBUFC=0 -DWITH_FCGI=0 -DWITH_CURL=1
```

and then I got it:

```
--   * LIBXML2: /usr/lib64/libxml2.so

--   * POSTGIS: /usr/lib64/libpq.so

--   * GEOS: /usr/lib64/libgeos_c.so

--   * FastCGI: disabled

--   * PROTOBUFC: disabled

--   * Oracle Spatial: /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntsh.so;/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libocci.so;/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libnnz12.so

--   * Exempi XMP: disabled

--  * Optional features

--   * WMS SERVER: ENABLED

--   * WFS SERVER: ENABLED

--   * WCS SERVER: ENABLED
```

Comment: If anyone needs to compile gdal with OCI you need to:


export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64

sudo sudo vi /etc/profile.d/oracle.sh && sudo chmod o+r /etc/profile.d/oracle.sh 
export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin

Important: ln -s /usr/include/oracle/11.2/client64 $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/public

or: copy oci.h and all the other stuff of the directory /usr/include/oracle/11.2/client64 to $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/public

Comment: To get the "oci.h"-File: the oracle-instanclient AND the oracle--instanclient-devel must be installed, e.g. by  zypper install oracle-instantclient11.2-devel-11.2.0.4.0-1.x86_64.rpm