# Configuring mapserv with Oracle on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: mapserver, oracle-spatial, ubuntugis, compile

I am new for mapserv over Ubuntu 22.04.
I had use ms4w and there are lots of things I don't know how to configure and use.
And the first thing is compiling with Oracle

I had Oracle Client installed ok, because `sqlplus` is running

I'm following instructions in

https://mapserver.org/installation/unix.html?highlight=compiling+over+ubuntu#compiling-on-unix

Well, after fighting several weeks I'm at this point. And I've never got mapserv to compile for Oracle.

I had also read [MapServer with Oracle-Spatial on Linux](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/328817/mapserver-with-oracle-spatial-on-linux).

I had run the following and I can't have mapserv compile for ORACLE

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/mapserver \
        -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/local/pgsql/91:/usr/local:/opt:/usr/share:/usr/lib:/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64:/usr/include/oracle/12.2/client64:/usr/lib:/usr/lib64:/usr/share/gdal \
        -DWITH_CLIENT_WFS=ON \
        -DWITH_CLIENT_WMS=ON \
        -DWITH_CURL=ON \
        -DWITH_SOS=ON \
        -DWITH_PHP=ON \
        -DWITH_PERL=ON \
        -DWITH_RUBY=ON \
        -DWITH_JAVA=ON \
        -DWITH_CSHARP=ON \
        -DWITH_PYTHON=ON \
        -DWITH_SVGCAIRO=OFF\
        -DWITH_ORACLESPATIAL=ON \
        -DWITH_MSSQL2008=ON \
  -DWITH_PROTOBUFC=OFF \
  -DWITH_HARFBUZZ=OFF \
  -DWITH_FRIBIDI=OFF \
        ../ >../configure.out.txt

And configure.out.txt shows this:


    -- Looking for lrint - found
    -- Looking for dlfcn.h
    -- Looking for dlfcn.h - found
    -- Performing Test HAVE_SYNC_FETCH_AND_ADD
    -- Performing Test HAVE_SYNC_FETCH_AND_ADD - Success
    -- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found version "1.2.11")
    -- Found PNG: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (found version "1.6.37")
    -- Found JPEG: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (found version "80")
    -- Found Freetype: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so
    -- Found PROJ: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so
    -- Found Proj 8.2
    -- Looking for iconv
    -- Looking for iconv - found
    -- Found iconv library:
    -- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.2")
    -- Checking for module 'cairo'
    --   Found cairo, version 1.16.0
    -- Found CAIRO: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so
    -- Found ORACLE: /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntsh.so;/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libocci.so;/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client>
    -- Found FCGI: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfcgi.so
    -- Found GEOS: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgeos_c.so
    -- Found POSTGRESQL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so
    -- Looking for PQserverVersion in pq
    -- Looking for PQserverVersion in pq - found
    -- Found GDAL: /usr/lib/libgdal.so
    -- Found CURL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so (found version "7.81.0")
    -- Found LibXml2: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so (found version "2.9.13")
    -- Found GIF: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgif.so (found version "5.1.9")
    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

**Some errors in CMakeError.log**
Determining if the function strrstr exists failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/sistemas/Descargas/mapserver-7.6.4/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/gmake -f Makefile cmTC_91b68/fast && /usr/bin/gmake  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_91b68.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_91b68.dir/build
gmake[1]: Entering directory '/home/sistemas/Descargas/mapserver-7.6.4/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_91b68.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o
/usr/bin/cc  -I/home/sistemas/Descargas/mapserver-7.6.4/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/math.h -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=strrstr -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_91b68.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o -c /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.c
Linking C executable cmTC_91b68
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_91b68.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc  -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=strrstr -rdynamic CMakeFiles/cmTC_91b68.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o -o cmTC_91b68  -lm 
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/cmTC_91b68.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o: in function `main':
CheckFunctionExists.c:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `strrstr'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_91b68.dir/build.make:99: cmTC_91b68] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/home/sistemas/Descargas/mapserver-7.6.4/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
gmake: *** [Makefile:127: cmTC_91b68/fast] Error 2



Determining if the function strlcat exists failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/sistemas/Descargas/mapserver-7.6.4/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/gmake -f Makefile cmTC_3779f/fast && /usr/bin/gmake  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_3779f.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_3779f.dir/build
gmake[1]: Entering directory '/home/sistemas/Descargas/mapserver-7.6.4/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_3779f.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o
/usr/bin/cc  -I/home/sistemas/Descargas/mapserver-7.6.4/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/math.h -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=strlcat -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_3779f.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o -c /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.c
Linking C executable cmTC_3779f
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_3779f.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc  -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=strlcat -rdynamic CMakeFiles/cmTC_3779f.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o -o cmTC_3779f  -lm 
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/cmTC_3779f.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o: in function `main':
CheckFunctionExists.c:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `strlcat'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_3779f.dir/build.make:99: cmTC_3779f] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/home/sistemas/Descargas/mapserver-7.6.4/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
gmake: *** [Makefile:127: cmTC_3779f/fast] Error 2



Determining if the function strlcpy exists failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/sistemas/Descargas/mapserver-7.6.4/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/gmake -f Makefile cmTC_51e8e/fast && /usr/bin/gmake  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_51e8e.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_51e8e.dir/build
gmake[1]: Entering directory '/home/sistemas/Descargas/mapserver-7.6.4/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_51e8e.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o
/usr/bin/cc  -I/home/sistemas/Descargas/mapserver-7.6.4/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/math.h -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=strlcpy -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_51e8e.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o -c /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.c
Linking C executable cmTC_51e8e
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_51e8e.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc  -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=strlcpy -rdynamic CMakeFiles/cmTC_51e8e.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o -o cmTC_51e8e  -lm 
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/cmTC_51e8e.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o: in function `main':
CheckFunctionExists.c:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `strlcpy'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_51e8e.dir/build.make:99: cmTC_51e8e] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/home/sistemas/Descargas/mapserver-7.6.4/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
gmake: *** [Makefile:127: cmTC_51e8e/fast] Error 2
```

Comment: This is the last configure.out.txt                                                                                        
 GNU nano 6.2                                                configure.out.txt
-- Found JPEG: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (found version "80")
-- Found Freetype: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so
-- Found PROJ: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-g

Comment: What errors were actually reported ? What do the make log files contain ? Especially the error log file.

Comment: i had edited the post whit error log